# Chromecast receiver app video takes very long time to start playing video

Tags: javascript, html, video, chromecast

Im currently using `window.videoElem.autoplay = true;` to start playing videos in my receiver app but I notice that a lot of the times when I tell the receiver to start the video at a start time other than 0 the videos wont start playing sometimes for 5 minutes after they've loaded.

The videos are playready drm protected and work fine when the start time is 0 but any other time could make the video not play.

I would like to be able to test not using the autoplay feature by implementing some listener pattern so I can start the video when I know for sure that everything has buffered and the player is in a state that can play the video. I have a feeling that somethings are happening asynchronously which is causing a race condition that throws an illegal state error that comes from one of the google cast library js files.

I tried looking at this: [cast-custom-reciever github](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-custom-receiver/blob/master/sample_media_receiver.html) but Ive written my receiver a bit different so Im not sure where to added my listeners for the state changes in the player that I could use to trigger playback once my conditions are met.

Does somebody have any idea how to attach a listener to trigger playback in the receiver app so I dont have to rely on the autoplayback feature?

**Edit:** Here is the error that gets thrown:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'buffered' property from 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source.
```

**Edit 2:** After some more debugging I can see that network requests from MediaPlayer.js are being made for audio only but not for video. There is an initial request for video at the start but then only audio afterwards.

Comment: I strongly suggest you stat using the reference receiver (Cast-Player-Sample: https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample) and if you don't see the callbacks that you need, come back here and explain exactly what callbacks you need and the use case so we can provide the a recommended approach for achieving that.

Comment: Hi Ali and thank you for replying.  I will look through there per your advice and see if I cant make sense of the listener pattern Im looking for. Thanks :)